# how to select records based on count of column field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a scenario that a query who will work like select records based on status = 1 with highly number of records found in database.
suppose i want to select artists who have max number of status = 1 with their names fetch from other table. 
another problem is my query is repetiting records.
my query:

```
SELECT order.status, 
       order.artist_id, 
       web_user.uFname, 
       web_user.uLname, 
          web_user.uID 
FROM `order` 
INNER JOIN `web_user` 
ON web_user.uID = order.artist_id 
HAVING order.status = '1'
```

my record set i am getting:

```
status artistid uFname   uLaname  uID
1      14       Pitbull  Armando  14
1      14       Pitbull  Armando  14
1      13       Enrique  Iglesias 13
1      15       Robyn    Rihanna  15
1      15       Robyn    Rihanna  15
1      15       Robyn    Rihanna  15
```

i simple want:

```
downloadtimes artistid uFname   uLaname      uID
2             14       Pitbull  Armando      14
1             13       Enrique  Iglesias     13
3             15       Robyn    Rihanna      15
```

please enhanced my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT()`

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS downloadtimes , 
order.artist_id, 
web_user.uFname, 
web_user.uLname, 
web_user.uID 
FROM `order` 
INNER JOIN `web_user` ON web_user.uID = order.artist_id 
WHERE order.status = '1'
GROUP BY order.artist_id
```

Comment: @user3040719 `COUNT(*) AS downloadtimes` is same as `COUNT(*)  downloadtimes` you just need to get the count of each group that is per artist

Comment: yes yes you are right Sir. thank you for the help and meaningful query.

Comment: thank you but its was keep saying 5minutes wait so i was unable to accept it and keep waiting. :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `count`

like:

```
COUNT(*) AS downloadtimes
```

you should just add the like you full code:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS downloadtimes , 
order.artist_id, 
web_user.uFname, 
web_user.uLname, 
web_user.uID 
FROM `order` 
INNER JOIN `web_user` ON web_user.uID = order.artist_id 
WHERE order.status = '1'
GROUP BY order.artist_id
```

and refer this following link:

[**SQL COUNT**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)